# excel vba, add multiple .To email addresses

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to send an email using VBA. But, no email is sent ... I think this is due to more than one email address in the '.To = ' code line. Is there a way of adapting the code to allow multiple email addresses?

I've tried looking at Ron de Bruin examples but, I just cant get anything to work?

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "bob.johnson@email.com, john.smith@email.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Open Orders where LF print to center of disc is required - " & Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm")
    .HTMLBody = "Please ensure discs for the following orders are run on replication lines that allow LF print to be printed to the center of the disc. " & Chr(10) & _
    RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Send
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ; instead of ,

```
.To = "bob.johnson@email.com; john.smith@email.com"
```

Comment: What gives you that idea, katz? ;)

Comment: hat the same but had to wait 3 minutes for my next post XD

Comment: fantastic; works 1st time

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the semicolon instead of comma:

```
With OutMail
    '.To = "bob.johnson@email.com, john.smith@email.com"
    .To = "bob.johnson@email.com; john.smith@email.com"
```